# How can I checksum a row in SQL vs a record in C# to detect changes?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I understand SQL has a checksum function which can calculate a hash based on all of the columns. Is it possible to duplicate this behaviour in C#, so that I can see if any fields in a record have changed in an object vs the database, and if they have, flag it up?

For example, I have an Employee table with first name, last name, date of birth. In C# I have an object with the same things, and in order to see if there is a change I have to compare each field against each other.

If I can do a checksum and store it in the table it'd be much faster, when I have a large number of employees (I think).

Is it possible to compute the same checksum in both so I can compare to see if there has been a change?

Comment: @Lanorkin I think that it's this http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms189788.aspx and not the Rowversion